# Write regular expression in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I still don't understand how regular expression work with preg_replace. I have some url in text:

> site.com/user/login.php?valid=tru
>
> site.com/eng/page/some_page.php?valid=tru&anothervar=1

I want to change it so it become this

> site.com/user/login/
>
> site.com/eng/page/some_page/

```
preg_replace(" 'no_mater_what_1'.php'no_mater_what_2' " , 'no_mater_what_1'/ , $some_var);
```

Comment: Do you need it for automatic redirecting or for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But why not simply do this:

```
$replace = explode('.php',$some_var);
$replace = $replace[0] . '/';
```

Because that I find it necessary to use a regular expression, because ".php" is not repeated in the string.

Comment: Assume a url like site.com/user/auth.phpscripts/login.php?no_care

Comment: Well, I do not think that the case be present, it is very unlikely

Comment: Thnx. Simple and usefull!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid traps, like an other `.php` substring in the path, you can use this replacement:

```
$url = preg_replace('~\.php(?:[?#]\N*|\z)~i', '', $url, -1, $c);
if (!$c) // not a php file, do something else
```

or in this way:

```
if (preg_match('~[^?#]+\.php(?=[?#]|\z)~Ai', $url, $m))
    $url = $m[0];
else
    // not a php file, do something else
```

This way ensures that the `.php` matched is the extension of the file because the regex engine will find the leftmost result that is followed by either a `?` for the query part, a `#` for the fragment part or the end of the string.

pattern elements:

- `\N`: a character that isn't a newline.
- `\z`: anchor for the end of the string.
- `A`: modifier that anchors the pattern at the start of the string
- `(?=...)`: lookahead assertion

The advantage of this approach is the safety with a good efficiency.

**An other way with [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)**:

You can use `parse_url` to separate an url into parts. If this way is a little fastidious because you need to rebuild the url after *(and the way you will rebuild it depends of the elements present in the url)*, it's however far from impossible and provides too a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$subject = 'site.com/eng/page/some_page.php?valid=tru&anothervar=1';

if (preg_match('/(.*)\.php(?:\?.*)/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1] .'/';
    echo $subject .' => '. $result;
} else {
    echo 'NOT FOUND';
}
```

The regular expression doing the *magic* is this

```
/(.*)\.php(?:\?.*)?/
```

by parts:

```
(.*)\.php
```

Capture everything until (excluding) ".php"

```
(?:\?.*)
```

Search for the pattern "?..."

```
?
```

Make that last pattern optional

Comment: Thanks for explaine! It will be usefull for me in future!

Answer (score 0):

Because your two examples shows up on the same line, this looks a bit confusing. However, it appears that you want to replace everything from .php to the end of the line with a /. So, use:

```
$new_link = preg_replace('/\.php.*$/', '/', $old_link);
```

You need the \ in front of the . because . is a special character that needs to be escaped to make it work like a period. Then, you look for php, in that order, followed by anything to the end of the line ($ means end of the line). You replace all of that with /.